# Answer ask in AkkaTestKit

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm trying to test my actor logic with AkkaTestKit. The problem is that my actor uses `ask` pattern. So I need to answer somehow. It look as this:

```
  case class AskExecution(id: Long)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case id : Long =>
      implicit val dispatcher = context.dispatcher
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
      val executor = sender

      //How to answer this?
      val f = executor ? AskExecution(id) map(v => v.asInstanceOf[Option[Long]]) 
      f.onComplete{
        case Success(k) =>
        case Failure(_) =>
      }
  }
```

In test I use it as follows:

```
val ca = TestActorRef(new TheActor())
ca ! 0L //I send 0, Now I want to answer the ask
        //How to do so?
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code easier to test, give your actor a reference to the executor actor (the actor that handles the `AskExecution` message).

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

class TheActor(executor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case id: Long =>
      val s = sender
      implicit val dispatcher = context.dispatcher
      implicit val timeout = 10.seconds
      (executor ? AskExecution(id)).mapTo[Option[Long]].pipeTo(s)
}

class Executor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case AskExecution(id) =>
      // do something to get a result
      val result: Option[Long] = ???
      sender ! result
  }
}
```

To [test](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/testing.html#asynchronous-testing-testkit), assuming your test class extends `TestKit` and mixes in the `ImplicitSender` trait:

```
val executor = system.actorOf(Props[Executor])
val theActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[TheActor], executor))

within(10.seconds) {
  theActor ! 0L
  expectMsgClass(classOf[Option[Long]])
}

// test the executor directly
within(10.seconds) {
  executor ! AskExecution(3L)
  expectMsgClass(classOf[Option[Long]])
}
```

Comment: It's even easier to inject a `TestProbe` and use it to verify that messages have been sent and respond to them. No need to create a new actor class, and particularly useful if other actor's behavior depends on state.